Date offset generating NO DATA in Looker studio scorecard
I would like some help with looker studio.
My aim is to create a data blend where i can compare sessions one year apart. My first step was to create a new metric, called date_offset_1_year.
Where I took the date and added one year to each date. this was done with this line of code: DATE(DATETIME_ADD(Date,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)). After this was done i created a new data blend where i joined the table with itself, using a left join and joining the date with date_offset_1_year. I also joined default channel grouping with default channel grouping and brand with brand. After this I added sessions to each table I was joining and renamed the right session value to sessions_offset.
Now to the problem, when adding sessions_offest to a scorecard i get NO DATA no matter what dates i choose but the session metric works fine. Both metrics work when i add them to a time series chart. What could be the problem?
I have tried filtering out session values equal to null, did not work!
EDIT(I have tried different date ranges and that seems to make a difference, if i choose advanced date filter 24 months back to 1 month back from today it works, but not i f I choose 12 months back to 1 month from today. This makes no sense right?)
